# Migration of Oracle and SQL server queries to Presto

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration, presto

I am trying to migrate my oracle and sql server queries to presto, I know there are certain difference between these two with presto as it's in ANSI SQL and others are in SQL like.

Need a help with the migration documentation, so that I can estimate how much time I will have to spend in refactoring the queries.

Similar docs:

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/migration/from-hive.html

Comment: I'm not sure why you think SQL Server and Oracle aren't also ANSI SQL? Of course, each database platform has it's own flavour of ANSI SQL, so that complicates matters.

Comment: That's correct , I am worried about the flavours ..  want to take this under consideration to avoid any last minute surprise

Comment: You’re going to need to migrate your queries on a case by case basis, I think.